# Can I use this ram (PHOTO) with this motherboard "GIGABYTE GA-F2A88XM-D3H"

Tags: windows-10, memory, motherboard, ddr3

Can I use this ram (PHOTO) with this motherboard [GIGABYTE GA-F2A88XM-D3H](https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/GA-F2A88XM-D3H-rev-30/sp#sp)?

8GB PC3-12800R (DDR3-1600Mhz, 2RX4) hynix - p/n: 647651-571

[image]

Answer (score 4):

No.

[The Hynix memory module in your photo](https://www.skhynix.com/eolproducts.view.do?pronm=DDR3+SDRAM&srnm=HMT31GR7CFR4C&rk=20&rc=module) is a [registered DIMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_memory). This is a special type of memory usually used in servers. It will not work in most desktop hardware, including your motherboard.

Comment: This is the correct answer

Comment: Oh shit, I didn't notice it was registered. I've removed my invalid answer.